# Compile Error Unless .svc File Is Open in VS 2010

Tags: wcf, compiler-construction, vsto

I have a very simple .svc file (VSTOService.svc) for some web services being offered up in VSTO:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" 
    Debug="true" Service="MyCompany.Communications.VSTOService" 
    Factory = "MyProject.Communications.IocServiceHostFactory" 
    CodeBehind="VSTOService.cs"%>
```

This file is in a Communications project that is one of 12 projects in my solution. As long as 
the file is open in the VS source editor, the entire solution compiles just fine. If, however, the file is closed, I get compile errors.

When I compile the Communications project by itself, I have the same problem, with two compile errors:
Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @
A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or method

Clearly, I haven't specified a namespace in the .svc file, but just in case, I also checked the two classes in the project. They are fine. I also tried to remove the space between the @ and the "ServiceHost" but VS insists on putting it back in when I save the file. (I **hate** it when software/hardware gives me lip!)

So, what is causing this entirely bizarre behavior?

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @ServiceHost Language="C#" 
    Debug="true" Service="MyCompany.Communications.VSTOService" 
    Factory = "MyProject.Communications.IocServiceHostFactory" 
    CodeBehind="VSTOService.cs"%>
```

move `@` sign with ServiceHost as `<% @ServiceHost` and hopefully your error get resolved

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that doesn't work, either. Actually, I have to jump through all sorts of hoops to use that format because VS2010 reformats <% @ServiceHost... to <%@ ServiceHost... I actually have to make the change, click on another edit tab, then save all, to prevent VS2010 from reformatting. (Yes, I can disable reformatting, but it's useful for many other things.) In any event, when I go through that rigmarole, I still get the error. Weirdness!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you create the *.svc file that it does not create a *.svc.cs file. If it does, delete it and remove the CodeBehind attribute from @ServiceHost

Answer (score 0):

I saw that my svc file is like

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MessageProcessor.Async" %>
<a href="Msg.svc">Msg.svc</a>
```

Don't know how the anchor tag got inserted below servicehost tag, which was causing the issue.
after removing anchor tag (), it fixed the issue "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or method"